# What is best approach for Mobile compatible views?

Tags: joomla-3.4, mobile-web-design

We are developing a component for joomla 3.x and we would like to design our component front end views mobile compatibility.

We know joomla uses bootstrap 2.x where mobile compatible is very limited.

Is there any best approach/framework available to design it mobile and joomla compatible.

Basically the component contains list (rows and columns) and edit (simple form with 1 or 2 columns).

Regards 
Malai

Comment: Could you look at existing theme frameworks that are based on bootstrap3 such as: http://www.t3-framework.org/ - to see how they handle frontend editing?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think bootstrap 2.x mobile compatibility is 'that' very limited. It's  powerful enough to do the the basic mobile compatibility things, especially when you just need it for displaying rows and columns.

In my opinion as a template designer, I think the best approach to design component view / layout is to code it as native/standard as possible you can, and let user to extend the looks the from the template side (that's the reason why the Joomla template override feature exist).

Using a non native way to code the component view, will possibly end up on isolated looks / style for your component. This will force template designers to do extra styling efforts when designing a template, to make the component look matches the global looks of the website.

Comment: What I've seen is components giving the OPTION to load bootstrap and they build on that. If the site already has it, the site builder simply unchecks that box and looks to see if the component loads okay on the front end. If it doesn't work right, they check the box and look at it again. The only issue is with sites that use another framework like Uikit. Then you end up with TWO frameworks, but honestly, it's better than you having to write your OWN framework for your component.